# Comparing identical strings using String.equals is found getting skipped

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Below is my code

```
                    for(int j=0;j<6;j++){
             //checking each deal

              dealname=driver.findElement(By.id("MainContent_dtlstAllDeals_lblDealTitle_"+j)).getText();
            // System.out.println(dealname);

              String result[]=dealname.split("\\.");

              String resultTitle=result[0];
                //System.out.println(resultTitle);

              String splitDealname=DealTitle.substring(0,resultTitle.length());     

              if(splitDealname.equals(resultTitle)){

             System.out.println("***whoooooo you got it********"+j+"position"+"in"+i+"page");

             //click on view deal button

             driver.findElement(By.id("MainContent_dtlstAllDeals_lbtnView_"+j)).click();

             Thread.sleep(5000);
            //System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("MainContent_lblDealTitle")).getText());

             String name=driver.findElement(By.id("MainContent_lblDealTitle")).getText();
             //verify selected deal is correct 
             System.out.println(name);

             //Thread.sleep(5000);

             try {
                if (name.equals(DealTitle)) {
                    System.out.println("whoos...verified");
                }
                /*               
                 String statuss=veifyTitle(""); 

                 if(statuss.equals("success")){
                 {
                 System.out.println("whoos...verified");
                 //do buying process

                 }


                 }
                 else{}*/
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                System.out.println(e);
            }



            }
```

Even though variables DealTitle and name contain same long string as below , that above code is not working.I have put the code in for loop , but when the 'if' condition is run it goes to next iteration .I found it while debugging

Detailed Interior Cleaning + Exterior Car Wash (External Foam Wash, Shampooing, Conditioning, Engine Room Wash, Tyre Polishing) Using AUTOGLYM Brand Products for Just Rs. 399 from Hasten Auto, Vennala (76% OFF)-pramod

Pls help.

Comment: _But my problem is that above code is not working_ elaborate it

Comment: [Writing the perfect question](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) or [how to ask a question on the internet and get it answered](http://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-the-Internet-and-Get-It-Answered) or http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Post all the code and the exception that you are catching. Pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got issue solved by using replace all method

```
String excelTitle=  DealTitle.replaceAll("[^\\w\\s\\-_]", "");

String pageTitle=name.replaceAll("[^\\w\\s\\-_]", "");


                if(excelTitle.compareTo(pageTitle)==0){
                    System.out.println("ok strings are same");
                }
```

Or you can use name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "")